# "strptime" in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

How to convert atom `'2015-12-15T05 PST'` to timestamp or datetime?

I've tried [parse_time/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=timedate#parse_time/3)

```
?- parse_time('2015-12-15T05 PST', '%Y-%m-%dT%H %Z', Stamp)
false.
```

and [format_time/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=timedate#format_time/3)

```
?- format_time('2015-12-15T05 PST', '%Y-%m-%dT%H %Z', date(Y,M,D,H,M,S,O,TZ,DST)).
ERROR: format_time/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, the mode of `format_time/3` can't really help you, because it's expecting everything to be passed in:

> format_time(+Out, +Format, +StampOrDateTime)

This means you supply each of the arguments. You want to see something with a `-` prefix which means it's handing something back, which seems like it would mean `parse_time/3`, but there the documentation says:

> Supported formats for `Text` are in the table below.

and it then proceeds to list exactly two options, `rfc_1123` and `iso_8601`, neither of which really match your format. There does not seem to be a way to supply a format code here, which I find really puzzling, because there are underlying Unix libraries here that can certainly do this.

However, the problem can be solved with everyone's favorite tool: definite clause grammars! Here's my solution:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

myformat(date(Y,M,D,H,_,_,_,TZ,_)) -->
    integer(Y), "-", integer(M), "-", integer(D),
    "T", integer(H), " ", timezone(TZ).

timezone('UTC') --> "UTC".
timezone('UTC') --> "GMT".
timezone(-18000) --> "PST".
timezone(Secs) -->
    [Sign], digit(H0), digit(H1), digit(M0), digit(M1),
    {
     (Sign = 0'+ ; Sign = 0'-),
     number_codes(Hour, [H0,H1]),
     number_codes(Minutes, [M0, M1]),
     (Sign = 0'+
     -> Secs is Hour * 3600 + Minutes * 60
     ;  Secs is -(Hour * 3600 + Minutes * 60))
    }.

my_time_parse(Atom, Date) :-
    atom_codes(Atom, Codes),
    phrase(myformat(Date), Codes).
```

I'm sure the learned will see ways to improve this code but it did the trick for me with your sample data. You will unfortunately need to either enumerate timezones or find a better source of data on them (perhaps parsing the system timezone definitions?) but if you know a-priori that you only need to handle PST, you can try it. Here's an example:

```
?- my_time_parse('2015-12-15T05 PST', Date).
Date = date(2015, 12, 15, 5, _G3204, _G3205, _G3206, -18000, _G3208) ;
false.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: very cool solution. I learned a lot from your answer. I just wish for a more convenient solution :).

Comment: Me too… I'm not entirely sure why the situation sucks so much, but once you have time, you can use [julian](http://mndrix.github.io/julian/), which is really fun!

Answer (score 0):

Coming late to this question: the desired format is *close* to iso_8601, which would take the format `"2015-12-15T05-08"`. To replace the time zone  `" PST"` with `"-08"`, we can use `append`. For code:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

timezone(" PST", "-08").
timezone(" PDT", "-07").
%% etc

convert_time(Date, Stamp) :- 
    timezone(Zone, Delta),
    append(Front, Zone, Date),
    append(Front, Delta, Date2),
    string_chars(Date3, Date2),
    parse_time(Date3, iso_8601, Stamp).

test :-
    convert_time("2015-12-15T05 PST", Stamp),
    writeln('Stamp'=Stamp),
    fail.
```

with output

```
?- test.
Stamp=1450184400.0
false.
```